# Unit test Spring Boot for two beans that implement a service interface in one test class

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, dependency-injection

On my service layer of Spring Boot web application I have a service interface with several methods and two implementing beans.

```
interface VehicleService { }
@Service
class CarServiceImpl implements VehicleService {}
@Service
class BycicleServiceImpl implements VehicleService {}
```

I have generated unit test for one of the services as so

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CarServiceTest {

  @TestConfiguration
  static class VehicleServiceTestContextConfiguration {
      @Bean
      public VehicleService vehicleService() {
         return new CarServiceImpl();
      }
  }

  @Autowired
  private VehicleService vehicleService;

  @Test
  public void getCar() throws Exception {
    //tests here with CarServiceImpl object
  }

}
```

When I want to run tests `BicycleServiceImpl` bean I will have to copy and paste same class and change `@Bean` to return `BicycleServiceImpl` which doesn't seem to be best solution. Is there any way I can run same test class twice and inject each bean one by one. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using Spring at all instead of just running plain unit tests against the service classes? Additionally, with any real-world example your two different service classes should have some sort of different behavior (or what's the point?), and your unit tests should differ accordingly.

Comment: I edited my post, I am actually testing service layer of Spring Boot application which provides REST services. You are correct two services do have a slightly different behavior but nothing that can't be controlled with simple `if-else`, so if I could figure out how to run each test twice using both implementing beans then it should be all set

Comment: Avoid conditionals when possible, *especially* when you're using them to switch between types. Create an abstract base class for your test and use abstract methods to delegate the implementation-specific behavior to implementation-specific test classes.